# "Potential memory leak" with std::function

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Consider this example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using closure_type = std::function<void(void)>;
using closure_vec = std::vector<closure_type>;

class callbacks {
    static closure_type common(std::string name, uint32_t number) {
        return [number, name]() { std::cout << name << number << std::endl; };
    }
public:
    static closure_type foo(uint32_t number) { return common("foo ", number); }
    static closure_type print(std::string msg) {
        return [msg]() { std::cout << "print " << msg << std::endl; };
    }
};

template <typename... calls_t> closure_vec wrap(uint32_t number, calls_t &&... calls) {
    return closure_vec {
        callbacks::foo(number),
        std::forward<calls_t>(calls)...,
    };
}

int main() {
    auto vec = wrap(42,
        callbacks::print("hello, "),
        callbacks::print("world"));

    for(auto &e: vec)
        e();
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYhAAZgBWUgAHVCFCc1o7Rxc3WPjEuh8/QKcQsKijTBMzOgYCZmICFOdXd2NMUySKqoIcgODQiOihSuratIb%2B9t9O/O6ogEojVAdiZA4pHXDfZEcsAGpNcJsANyaiYh3sTRkAQRW1jcxt3b7iX2ATs8vtVdp1hy2dmyoHT5lWhsF4XK6fG53GzmB6YZhOUGXC4OBLqTbreLzTAAfQIAE8YrcdgARTZ9dAgED/QFJX57VB4dAQemMqYvcL6ZGo4Do1iY4g4g7IO6k8mUoVHX4YoRY3EEzDszlI87rZhCITotisILMZAAaw1mgA7ErNmayZUzMLpbL8YT0agnE46BAxSAHk9NsCnJhSJsHL4COFtLivV1iFNtibXubY5sBQR5rRtpFdLRw37vQrIsSIJHjboLRSUHMCFDfl74UTdhX0xNiOXdkXKZ5WDtC8bie2Y%2BbO68Yg4gqw8MgQD2zX1mFbefycXbbjRUBAA/Rg6G6wV8yb45hE8Rk2gnS6dNpF9ttO4w/W2Ryo12LrHJ9ObQK5faYo96K6CMWPWinEIwBbqacZmgmSYproAHPDmeZRoWbpoA4Za/BWJ4foG57aI2NibNBOHNiArbtne3YPr2Rr3pclFkcqBCYE4MSqPRULzlmAB0nGaqwrBCLiJwzjKr5CpsADuxDMDEy6BmuZYbqEfosDxfEodoABsOhqZx7HcbxwHjjue4HnyQmCk08EGbGSnarqBqUouEDyRGpCWeabo0MQolVOgUpaipJwQNZQhTNpLnkWafYcq8fZghcmFOMwvhwQWBnMMhqCbCJJJiRJUncO4rlmtZOr6kIlIYV%2BJ4ICUfJ%2BieMyFbpJV2SAFUEBAJ6iSQrA%2BReUw3kqBkeRAaVEOeakcJlTRsuFcaYHmtGxuB%2B6bDItGdlIMysNIkTyK4sjyKg0g2AYBhknMCxEu8nDyAQ0hyP1pB6iA3DhOxnBGjIakABwAJwyJE2icJwamcOEKjSNwe33Yd0jyGVMikHdB0zHAsBIIeMR4OwZAUIFjpYzjKCqOonAyOTfDY/RxBlRA2L0zIlAzEEMOkEEvhVHi0g3aQh4%2BvQADytCsFzB2kFgCXqOwrP4AKzQHGVYuYOITTIUsPOBiUrMKAAjg4oSi292jvfI7DqAQSCcCoeBBBJxB4nYWCsx%2BmB7ALQQKIclD09ijN5ioVjABbygu27Hte3TDOUAoACK%2Bv28GZO/b92hGpEMip%2BEanaN9Rofb9nCUPgQhMcwoubVtgfB5wj0EI8TgwzM/CMEpHA8HwdAEMIYiSGLSjuCTGinXo1tBGVkAzKgMRAorAC0AvYbP5IkloegGB9myzwA6q7BsW562%2B0Kgs%2Br/oei/d9J8E1Om9b0fJ/J1fjFTvDJSHEkljWIMrhW54HR5AUEOmQgTfyAQkIE/9wzKEaM0coIxQFWxgUCVo1RIH1mgfA%2BwdQMFtDQYAmusx5iLC4FtHa0MxZHSkOIb6alZ5qW4LyNQPIybsRkKwzYEBcCEBIOecIVtNh2EYtjUIvDtCRhOmvPQt1G4zGeu8di3BfqRF%2BkaI0oNuCRHTpEXg20pBQ1IA3MmiN9pyFIJQ%2BGIBEbIweqQNGiAQBEHsOQSgVRgCK3kK4oQog1AlAYAgVAolubyExsIsI7hMD4COMoZuTA2Bt14M3buEhWbkl8HDIwP5fDeL8KwPxAT9o80cawAAkhSVU5tGR4jrgCPUpBxKSSCaQqQu1SAmNhlIcpwBZ5mHQHiDh1TaB6nzO8bColCAIE2NQ2h9DGFohYWw0x1iK5PQiG9cI6yNmbM2RDPR5DTHmKMJYpGMidnaD2e06RKMZgHBph/bgQA)</kbd> (On the right most tab there is a full message)

When this code is checked with clang-tidy, I get the following warning:

```
warning: Potential memory leak [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]
```

The line number points at the scope exit of the `wrap` function.

As I understand the message, the tool is concerned that the results form `callbacks::foo` might be lost. But I don not understand how is it possible: `std::function` is a safe class and should destroy everything nicely in its destructor. Also its lifetime is controlled by the vector which is safe too.

What is going on here? How do I fix this or workaround?

Unfortunately I cannot just suppress the warning, as this code is scattered everywhere in the codebase.

Comment: I see no dynamic allocations here, hence no memory leaks are possible. The possible explanations are: 1) the leak is from code that's not shown, 2) the C++ library is leaking, 3) The leak detection tool is defective.

Comment: "the leak is from code that's not shown" - I posted minimal example that reproduces the issue, so it's not the case.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but a class with nothing but static members generally ought to be a namespace.

Comment: Seems like clang-tidy doesn't like something about libstdc++'s implemention of `std::function`. Adding `-stdlib=libc++` makes the warning go away. So I guess Sam was kinda right. The problem is in code you don't show... but it isn't your code at all.

Comment: Does it happen if you don't use an initializer list?  Replace `wrap` with a body that either moves from a (std) array or reserves & comma fold executes emplace back moves?

Comment: I shown all the code I have, unless you mean my standard library :-) It's literally a self contained example that reproduces the problem in Godbolt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
closure_vec retval;
retval.reserve(sizeof...(calls)+1);
retval.push_back(callbacks::foo(number));
( retval.push_back(std::forward<calls_t>(calls)), ... );
return retval;
```

this avoids the const initializer_list contained copies of std function your code created, so should be more efficient as well.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/xM14Wf4GY).

I tried using a C style array here, but I got the warning as well despite not using a std::initializer_list.

This also works:

```
std::array<closure_type, sizeof...(calls)+1> tmp ={
    nullptr,
    std::forward<calls_t>(calls)...
};
tmp[0] = callbacks::foo(number);
return {std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(tmp)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(tmp))};
```

the problem is `callbacks::foo(number)` within the initalization.

Comment: Also storing `callbacks::foo(number)` in a variable and using it in the initializer list works too. I guess something about `std::function` moving is broken.

Comment: @ivaigult But only when used to initialize as a prvalue.